# AngularJS Nested ng-repeat and ng-if on JSON file

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I'm trying to figure out how to iterate through a JSON file and grab the children of a particular data item. I know this is going to require the use of nested ng-repeaters, as I am using angularJS, but I can't seem to get it to output anything. Any ideas?

Note: I use an ng-if to only take in the children of the id "someIdPassedIn".

My HTML:

```
<span ng-repeat="item in dataItems">
    <span ng-if="item.id == someIdPassedIn">
        <span ng-repeat="child in item.children">
            {{ child.id }}
        </span>
    </span>
</span>
```

My JSON file:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "test1",
        "children": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "child"
            }
        ]
    }, 
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "test2",
        "children": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "child"
            }
        ]
    }, 
    {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "test3",
        "children": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "child"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: Looks like your property names in your template are incorrect.

Comment: Adding a plunker can help.  Or at the bare minimum include your controller code.  A lot of angular problems are the result of mismatched names, etc.

Comment: Not related to your issue, is there a reason that you're using `ng-if` on a child element instead of filtering the `dataItems` list in the `ng-repeat`? Usually I would do something like `ng-repeat="item in dataItems | filter:{id:someIdPassedIn}"` and wouldn't have a child element with the `ng-if`.

Comment: I read somewhere that filters won't take in variables. I guess that source was wrong. Thanks for help to clean up my code, squid!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the limited amount of information available, it appears as though the property names in your template are incorrect.  I took a shot at fixing them, maybe it will point you in the right direction if it's not quite perfect.

```
<span ng-repeat="item in dataItems">
    <span ng-if="item.id == someIdPassedIn">
        <span ng-repeat="child in item.children">
            {{ child.id }}
        </span>
    </span>
</span>
```

Comment: My apologies. I failed to change the id when posting it on SO. The problem still exists.

Comment: children.item in your post is still incorrect.  Try item.children.

Comment: Argh, typo again. Fixed. Problem still exists. Sorry about that.

Comment: I think you better create a plunker with the problem.

Comment: As it turns out, my syntax was correct. I had to manually refresh my JSON file (which my browser had cached) with the new file structure before it would read it. Thanks for spending your time on this.